# Insert into PERSOANE table return violates check constraint but shouldn't

Tags: postgresql

This is my creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSOANE (
idPers numeric (5)
    CONSTRAINT pk_persoane PRIMARY KEY,
NumePren varchar (30)
    CONSTRAINT ck_nume CHECK (NumePren=LTRIM(INITCAP(NumePren))), 
Loc varchar (30)
    CONSTRAINT nn_loc NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT ck_loc CHECK (Loc=LTRIM(INITCAP(Loc))),
Jud varchar (25)
    CONSTRAINT nn_jud NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT ck_jud CHECK (Jud=LTRIM(INITCAP(Jud))),
Tel numeric (10)
    CONSTRAINT nn_tel NOT NULL,
E_mail varchar(254)
    CONSTRAINT nn_e_mail NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT ck_e_mail CHECK (E_mail = LTRIM(E_mail))
);
```

When I try to insert values in the table I got error: new row for relation "persoane" violates check constraint "ck_jud" Here is my insert script:

```
INSERT INTO PERSOANE VALUES (11111, 'slimi marius', 'oras', 'judet', 0752361507, 'simic@yahoo.com');
```

Anyone has any suggestion how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initcap()` will change the first character to uppercase. So your check constraints on the columns `numepren`, `loc` and `jud` require you to enter values where the first character of every word is in uppercase. In the value `'jude'` the first character is lowercase, so the check constraint is violated. You need to use `'Jude'` instead. This is also true for the other columns you have defined:

```
INSERT INTO PERSOANE 
(idpers, numepren, loc, jud, tel, e_mail)
  VALUES 
(11111, 'Slimi Marius', 'Oras', 'Judet', 0752361507, 'simic@yahoo.com');
```

Comment: Thx, didn't pay attention.